# Get and add next row column value to first row column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table which as below
[image]

I want to add each **SoldD** column to next row **ValT** column.
for example, query result for above given table should be like as
[image]

**Above snapshot is for expected Results**

so for, I have tried many things but failed to get expected results

Failed try 1:

```
SELECT *,(IFNULL((SELECT VaIT from saleorder s WHERE s.id > ss.id limit 1),0)+ss.SoldD) FROM `saleorder` ss
```

Failed try 2:

```
update saleorder SET SoldD=(IFNULL((SELECT VaIT from (SELECT * from saleorder WHERE id > id+1 limit 1) s),0)+SoldD)
```

Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [plain text](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for your table not images

Comment: @AlbertoMoro is there any problem in using images?

Comment: yes [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10662353)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Mysql version is  5.5

Comment: One problem with images is that they attract downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql version:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE id2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare VALT2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare soldD2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare beforSo2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, ValT, SoldD FROM saleorder ORDER BY id;
    OPEN cur1;
    FETCH cur1 INTO id2, VALT2, soldD2;
    SET valT2 = soldD2;
    x: LOOP
        IF(valT2 IS NULL) THEN
            SET valT2 = 0;
        END IF;
        IF(beforSo2 IS NULL) THEN
            SET beforSo2 = 0;
        END IF;

        UPDATE saleorder
        SET SoldD = beforSo2 + valT2
        WHERE ID = id2;

        SET beforSo2 = beforSo2 + valT2;
        FETCH cur1 INTO id2, VALT2, soldD2;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Then call procedure this way:

```
CALL new_procedure;
```

SqlServer version:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, ValT, SoldD FROM Table_2 ORDER BY ID; 
DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @valT  INT;
DECLARE @soldD INT;
DECLARE @beforSoldD INT = 0;
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @valT, @soldD;
SET @valT = @soldD;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    IF(@valT IS NULL)
        SET @valT = 0;
    IF(@beforSoldD IS NULL)
        SET @beforSoldD = 0;

    UPDATE Table_2
    SET SoldD = @beforSoldD + @valT
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    SET @beforSoldD = @beforSoldD + @valT;

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @valT, @soldD;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Base data:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does that work with MySQL? Looks more like SQL server style.

Comment: Yes @Shawn its showing me following error when I execute it in mysql         Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 0)
SQL query: Documentation

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, ValT, SoldD FROM Table_2 ORDER BY ID

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, ValT, SoldD FROM Table_2 ORDER BY ID' at line 1

Comment: Yes, I've done it in SqlServer. I just wanted to convey the main idea of my solution in SQL(because of your SQL tag in your question). I hope there is a way you can do it in your case.

Comment: @SaeidAmini thank you so much for you effort, can you please append your answer and do this in mysql too?